# how much of a bad practice is it to use links instead of copy?

Tags: filesystems, symbolic-link

Currently my work flow is that for every presentation/paper I'm writing I create a folder with a subdirectory for figures. I want to  have a central figures directory, and simply simlink to it whenever I create a folder. Is this considered a bad practice? What should I be aware of?

Comment: How are you creating the symlinks? There are different types and they have different ramifications.

Comment: ``ln -s local_folder /path/to/main/folder``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is neither a good nor a bad practice. It simply means that you need to maintain the central directory, or the folders might end up with broken symlinks and the presentations cease working.

You might want to use hard links if available, so that at least you can keep track of how many "users" there are for each picture and recognize unused pictures for cleanup (or you might not care, if you've lots of available space).

Or if you have a way to identify all presentation folders, you might set up a script that searches those, and looks for used and unused pictures, maybe even listing the presentations for each picture (and/or vice versa)

```
home / presentations
     / pictures
     / pictures / unused
```

I had something like this for a product gallery on a web site. I can confirm that `find` and a little `awk` is enough to keep symlink hell under control.

> Some images related to usage, generics, or whole families of products are repeated in multiple products. Most products start with a generic image or images, evolve with a slightly less generic "product family" set of images, and often but not always settle on one or several specific images when the marketing guys get their act together. Months later, the product might get retired, and the images become useless... but some of them might have meanwhile been adopted by other products. Cleanup became an issue a long time ago.